# Is `validates` a class method or an instance method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having a hard time understanding how we are able to write the following line:

```
validates :email, presence: true
```

What I think is that this is the class method since the following code executes perfectly in Rails.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.validates :email, presence: true
end
```

But when I go to Rails' source code, I come to know that `validates` is an instance method, not a class method, and writing `self.validates` in class definition gives me an impression that it is class method.

This is how it has been defined in Rails:

```
def validates(*attributes)
    defaults = attributes.extract_options!.dup
    validations = defaults.slice!(*_validates_default_keys)

    raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one attribute" if attributes.empty?
    raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one validation" if validations.empty?

    defaults[:attributes] = attributes

    validations.each do |key, options|
      next unless options
      key = "#{key.to_s.camelize}Validator"

      begin
        validator = key.include?('::') ? key.constantize : const_get(key)
      rescue NameError
        raise ArgumentError, "Unknown validator: '#{key}'"
      end

      validates_with(validator, defaults.merge(_parse_validates_options(options)))
    end
end
```

What actually it is?

Comment: Instance method, of course. The question is, on which object? :)

Comment: In case you didn't know, classes are objects in ruby and they have instance methods too (what you probably think of as "class methods", but there is no such thing in ruby)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd say that I was less-confused before. :) Would you like to refer me any article or resource to get this thing further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [*class instance* method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) :)

As Sergio points in the comments, since every class in Ruby is an object (instance of class [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html)), `validates` is a method of `Class`'s instance.

Your `User` class inherits bunch of stuff from [`ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L277). Among this inherited stuff there is [Validations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L303) module.

---

**Sidenote:**
Watch this [coolest video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2sgQ38UDVY) about **Ruby object model** by [Dave Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Thomas_(programmer)) - things will become much-much more clear!

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but I think I _really_ need to go deep down into the *class-object-stuff* to really understand this thing.

Comment: @ArslanAli: read a book called "metaprogramming ruby", it should help

Comment: @ArslanAli see the edit and yeah! Metaprogramming Ruby is also great tool to understand what you need